# Convert STL file into OBJ format

Tags: api, file, stl, converters, 3d-model

Looking to convert STL file to OBJ file. Searched a lot of options online. They all seem to offer that, including API services, but when it comes to converting specifically STL->OBJ, they ALL return error. I think it is related to a lack of texture map file that OBJ format needs and which STL format simply does not have. I want to integrate 3D model previewer into my website which is PHP. I could use STL directly, but then models don't look good. So the task is to convert for now adding our default texture map on a way. I already have OBJ viewer sorted out, just need to convert the file at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Use Open3d,

To convert .stl to .obj:

```
import open3d as o3d
mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("curve.stl")
o3d.io.write_triangle_mesh("curve.obj", mesh)
```

To convert .obj to .stl:

```
import open3d as o3d
mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("curve.obj")
mesh = o3d.geometry.TriangleMesh.compute_triangle_normals (mesh)
o3d.io.write_triangle_mesh("curve1.stl", mesh)
```

Replace "curve.obj", 'curve.stl' with your file names.